# How to check if a (made-up) store is open or closed between specific times just with an if/elseif statement?

Tags: php, if-statement

For a small PHP assignment for school (Using MAMP to display our page on localhost:8888) we had to create a page that displayed the following:

1. The date and time of today.
2. Create a If-else-elseif statement that checks if our fictive store was open between Monday - Friday (Closed on saturday and sunday), and open between 08:30 and 17:00, while displaying as closed outside of those times

**Approach number 1, that worked but I wasn't allowed to combine 'H' and 'i' together in `date("Hi")`.**

```
<?php

 $datum = date('D');
 $uren = date('H');
 $minuten = date('i');

 if($datum == 'Sat' || $datum == 'Sun') { 
          echo "The store isn't open in the weekends";
       } 
        elseif(date('Hi') < 830 || date("Hi") > 1700) {
            echo "the store is closed";
       } 
       else {
        echo "The store is open";
        }
    ?>
```

**I had to do the hours and minutes seperately, so: first iterate through the hours, then through the minutes. Approach 2:**

```
 <?php 
     $datum = date('N');
     $uren = date('H');
     $minuten = date('i');

          if($datum > 5) {
             echo "The store isn't open in the weekend";
            } elseif ($uren < 8 || $uren > 17) {
              echo "The store is closed";
            } elseif ($uren == 8 && $minuten < 30) {
              echo "The store is closed";
            } else {
                echo "The store is open";
                }

    ?>
```

According to my teacher, the overal setup seems to be somewhat alright, but I can't seem to figure out how I can iterate between the 2 hours (8 and 17) and ALSO the minutes (08:**30** and 17:**00**). Not sure if the above example is already going in the proper direction? but it is not working for me at least.

**My last attempt**

```
   <?php 
     $datum = date('N');
     $uren = date('H');
     $minuten = date('i');

     if($datum > 5) {
             echo "The store is not open in the weekends";
       } elseif($uren > 17 && ($uren < 8 || $uren === 8 && $minuten < 30)){
              echo "The store is closed";
            }
           else {
                   echo "The store is open";
                }
}
```

When I add `<?php  echo "The time is " . date("H:i:s"); ?>` and change the "H:i:s" values, the "It's open/closed" doesn't seem to respond to it (unless it's not the way to hardcode time).

What do i need to fix in my if-elseif-statement to make the very simple "Is it open"-checker work?

Comment: How true do you think `$uren > 17 && ($uren < 8 || $uren === 8 && x)` can ever become?

Comment: _"When I add `<?php  echo "The time is " . date("H:i:s"); ?>` and change the "H:i:s" values"_ - what do you mean by that, "change the H:i:s values"?

Comment: @04FS when i write down `date(12:32:06)` in stead of how it just displays the current time given by the local server (is that right?).

And welp, I have been working around all day to figure it out. my knowledge is pretty limited so far, so I was already thinking that `$uren > 17 ......` was not correct.

Comment: Weekends aside, you want the store to show as closed if the hour is >= 17, _or_ the hour is < 8, _or_ the hour is == 8 _and_ the minutes are <= 30.

Comment: `date(12:32:06)` makes absolutely zero sense - that is not even valid PHP syntax. The first argument of date is always the _format_, it has absolutely nothing to do with the current or specified actual timestamp.

Comment: @04FS Thank you for mentioning that, cause I wasn't sure at all if it would do that I thought it would do

Comment: If you want to simulate how your script would work at a given point in time - then you can use [`strtotime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to create an according unix timestamp, and then use that in all your `date` calls as second parameter.

Comment: @04FS Could you possibly give me your opinion on Approach number 2? I guess (again, limited knowledge) that what you had corrected me on for approach 3, is basically a re-written approach 2 right? Shouldn't approach number 2 be working? or is there an error in it or missing something.

Comment: `H` is 24-hour format with leading zeroes, so you should rather use `G` when comparing the result to integers. If that does not solve the issue, then do some actual _debugging_ - use `var_dump` or similar to check that what the variables contain, actually matches your expectations.